# Suggestion and auto-complete in form with one-to-many relationship in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, one-to-many, ms-access-2013

I am trying to make a form for a very typical scenario: a customer makes an order. The customer might be new or returning. I have created an Access database with two tables: Job and Customer (linked by the primary key 'customer no'). The form I wish to create looks like this:

[image]

The customer table data is highlighted.

When the customer's name is beginning to be typed in, I want to see an updating list suggesting possible customer matches. If the customer happens to be returning, I can click on one of the drop-down options and have all other customer fields auto-complete.

What is the best way to create such a form?

I tried to achieve this using a comboBox and some code. However, if I use this method, the comboBox does not allow me to enter a customer name which isn't already in the customer's table. So I can't enter new customer details.

Ideally, this auto-complete/suggestion should work for all customer fields, such as phone number (in case the phone number is the only know customer info).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combobox which has LimitToList set to false, allowing entry of data not already defined in the combobox's rowsource; With this approach you would define a not-in-list event handler for the combobox to open a popup form for adding a new customer, ideally pre-initialised with the customer name just entered, and when data is saved in that form, control returns to this form, requeries the combobox (as it's contained data is now out of date), re-locks the customer just added, and fires it's after update event to display all the relevant customer-related fields appearing on this form.

However whether this is appropriate or not depends to some extent on the quantity of data that you have. If you've more than say 10000 customers in the database, I'd recommend instead having an elipsis (...) button beside customer name which opens a popup search screen, and provides whatever search options seem best (name, number, city, etc) for the entity being searched, a textbox, and find + add buttons; With huge data quantities you might also want to provide a means to prevent searching for matches (especially by multiple users across a busy network) where there is less than say 4 characters in the textbox, to improve performance.

You'd then use the text_changed event on the textbox to retrieve the data in the database which starts with the text currently existing in the textbox, and display this in a datasheet; The user can then either click Find or double-click the datasheet to select a customer which you then return to the calling form, probably by either a call to a public sub, or setting a tag value on that form - or click Add to add a new customer and invoke logic similar to the above.

Comment: Good suggestions. Unfortunately, I really want the solution to be inline without the need for a pop-up. Mostly, the people using the form wont know if a customer is returning, and in 90% of cases the customers will be new. So a pop-up will either a) waste time in 90% of cases, or b) workers wont bother with the search and will just add duplicate customers.